Branch Points and Branch Line of the Function $f(z) = \cos^{-1}z$
I know the branch line and branch points of common function like $\log{z}$ and aware of the definitions. But what's the general approach here to find branch line and branch points of any multivalued functions let's say $\,\cos^{-1}{z}$ ,
So about this function I can express it in terms of logarithmic function as
$$ \cos^{-1}{z} = -i \log\left[z + i\sqrt{1 - z^2}\right]$$
hence it is a multivalued function.
So would its branch line the same as that of $\log{z}$.
Also, how the branch points are related to the zeroes of the functions? Why it is only that around zeroes there is a possibility that the function may not return to its original value and no other point?

The branch cut is not the same as for $\log z$ due to the presence of a square root, which itself has a branch cut. Branch points do not have to be zeros, for example $\sqrt z + \sqrt{1-z}$ has branch points 0, 1 and $\infty$.
